# PHP exec() with mixed quotes

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run the following ffmpeg command with PHP's exec(), but because of the need for double-quotes and single-quotes, exec() is failing.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /var/www/html/data/photos/576c2ecf766fe.png -vf "zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 5 -s hd1080 -crf 17 /var/www/html/ffmpeg/zoomout.mp4
```

How can I run this script via PHP?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what this means. Could you provide an example?

Comment: escaping the two inner double-quotes worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape whichever quote type you are using in the PHP for encapsulation. So presuming you have `exec('')` it would be:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /var/www/html/data/photos/576c2ecf766fe.png -vf "zoompan=z=\'if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))\':d=125" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 5 -s hd1080 -crf 17 /var/www/html/ffmpeg/zoomout.mp4
```

You can read more about PHP strings here, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. The heredoc and nowdoc also would work.